# WebStorm2017 How to print url as a link in Console window?

Tags: webstorm

**WebStorm version: 2017.1.4**

**System version: macOS 10.12.5**

Maybe in WebStorm 2016.x the console.info("http://localhost:3000") still show the url as a link in the Console window, but in WebStorm 2017 not:
[image]

I can see the PyCharm 2017.1.4 working well:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Works in [WebStorm 2017.2 EAP](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+EAP) - `console.log()` URLs are clickable:

[image]